# Random Number Repetition in a List

Tags: python, random

I am trying to create a code and Being a beginner in Python, I am having some trouble. So the code should to this:

It generates a random number with randint and put in into the list l = []
and do this as long as range.

Function repetition(l) that should check all numbers and returns the number of try(the postion(index)) of the first duplicate element.

Function repeater(count) that repeats 1-365 the repetition function long enough (1-365) and enumerating with the help of an array, until a repeat occurs.

```
import random

l = []

for _ in range(365):
    n = random.randint(1, 365)
    if n not in l:
    l.append(n)

print(l)
```

I think thats the same only int the in a funktion form:

```
numb = 365
def repetition(numb):
    for i in range(1,numb+1):
        i = random.randint(1, numb+1)
        if i not in l:
        l.append(n)

#def repeater(count):
```

Is is it also possible to do it with a dictionary instead of a list?

Stuck on step checking the Element and creating the repeater function

Comment: `repetition` *won't allow* any duplicates.

Comment: Obviously English is not your native language, but you're going to have to do a better job at explaining your problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to edit the question to show an example of what you want out of the function? Say everything was set to 10 instead of 365 and `random.randint` came up with `[8, 3, 5, 4, 4, 1, 8, 1, 9, 4]`; what should your working code output?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok your ex. repetition function should print out that it takes seven random number to get the 8 twice, because its the first random number and and seventh

Comment: @Kate so only for the first number? Please *edit the question*; include as much detail as possible. You can even mock up exactly what you expect to see printed to the terminal.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes only the first one

Comment: @kate, is one function ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what the question is, but I wrote this from what I understood:

```
import random

TRIES = 365

def generate_random_numbers(n):
    """Generates a list of n random numbers"""

    random_numbers = []
    for _ in range(n):
        random_number = random.randint(1, n)
        random_numbers.append(random_number)

    return random_numbers

def repetition(random_numbers):
    """Given a list of random numbers, it will return the index of the first repeated element"""

    for index, random_number in enumerate(random_numbers):
        if random_number in random_numbers[:index]:
            # You can print the list up to but not including the first repeated element
            # using list slicing: print '{}'.format(random_numbers[:index])
            return index

def repeater(n):
    indices_of_first_duplicates = []
    for i in range(n):
        random_numbers = generate_random_numbers(n)
        indices_of_first_duplicates.append(repetition(random_numbers))

    return indices_of_first_duplicates


repeater_result = repeater(TRIES)

print '{}'.format(repetition(repeater_result))
```

In the code above, what `genearte_random_numbers` and `repetition` do is documented. `repeater` generates `n` list of random numbers. For each list, it finds the index of the first repetition and stores all those indices in a list and returns that list. Finally, from what I understood/guessed, you then want to see in the list return `repeater`, what is the index of the first duplicate (i.e. After how many tries is the same random number generate twice at the same index.)

I might be entirely on the wrong track so I do apologise if I've misunderstood your problem.

Comment: wow you're already a few steps further... but I try to print out the random number list and I get a huge list  the code don't stop and it also pritn out Took ... random numbers to repeat number ...

Comment: for every function it should print out separately,  just a moment  I try it know maybe I could do it

Comment: Still unsure what you mean but I've added a comment that might be of help :-)

Comment: really thanks i forgot to vote up but now yeap

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not totally sure, but I think this does what you want:

```
def repetition(numb):
    l = [random.randint(1, numb)]
    while True:
        n = random.randint(1, numb)
        l.append(n)
        if n == l[0]:
            return l
```

That will create a list where the first and last values are the same with other random numbers in between:

```
l = repetition(numb)
print(l)
print("Took {0} random numbers to repeat {1}".format(len(l), l[0]))
```

Example for `numb == 10`:

```
[8, 10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 8]
Took 7 random numbers to repeat 8
```

Comment: thats it but I add a print statement to see the list, if I edit l = repetition(10) I get  [7,3,2,2,3,1,2,9] Took 9 random numbers to repeat 9 why?

Comment: I can only assume you made a mistake in copying or editing the code; it works perfectly for me. Did you move the check against `l[0]` *before* the `append`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added print statement to see what is happening.

```
import random
numb = 20
def repetition(numb):
    l=[] # create a list
    for i in range(1,numb+1):
        i = random.randint(1, numb+1)
        l.append(i) # add i to list
        print l,i
        if len(l) > 1 and i == l[0]: # if list is longer than one element and i == first element
            return len(l) # return length of the list
repetition(numb)
[19] 19
[19, 21] 21
[19, 21, 19] 19
Out[21]: 3
```